# How to pass a string variable as type parameter argument, eg List(Of T) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, generics

I want to be able to pass the value of a string as a generic type argument. What kind of conversion process do I need.

I've gone around the houses using GetType and so on but a generic seems to want a literal.

In the following I want the equivalent of creating a List(Of Integer) but by using a variable for "Integer"

this next example works but it is not what I need:

```
Dim _list As List(Of Integer)
```

this next example would be what I need but it doesn't work

Test 1.

```
Dim _typeName As System.String = "Integer"

Dim _list As List(Of _typeName)
```

the following do not work either

Test 2.

```
Dim _type As Type = Type.GetType("Integer")

Dim _list As List(Of _type)
```

Test 3.

```
Dim _type As Type = Type.GetType(Of Integer)

Dim _list As List(Of _type)
```

Test 4.

```
Dim _typeName As System.String = "Integer"

Dim _type As Type = Type.GetType(_typeName)

Dim _list As List(Of _type)
```

They either throw up 
Keyword does not name a type
or 
Type '_typeName' is not defined

Comment: `this works but it is not what I need`  Why does that not work?

Comment: I believe you'll need to do this with reflection. Fundamentally you're trying to use a feature aimed largely at compile-time safety, but with only execution-time information.

Comment: To Jon's comment, a couple of things that might prove useful to you: You can use `GetType` on an incomplete generic type, which will give you a `Type` object that can be instantiated with a specific argument.  You can then use the `MakeGenericType` member on that incomplete type to try to create the specific type you want.  e.g. `Dim t = GetType(List(Of ))` and `Dim tt = t.MakeGenericType(GetType(Integer))`.

Comment: @Craig - The part that's missing for the OP is turing `Dim _typeName As System.String = "Integer"` into a `Type`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I thought that would be the easy part (and something where it would be fairly easy to find references).  The generic-specific parts are not things (I don't think) that you would run into as commonly, so they might be harder to find.

Comment: @Craig - There's no type called "Integer". That's the first problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity: As "Integer" is not the name of any type, you have to use a function with a ```Select Case``` and either return the correct type name ("System.Int32") or directly the type itself ```Return GetType(Int32)```.

Comment: @Christoph - Yes, of course, but the OP doesn't seem to know that.

Comment: @Enigmativity: that would suggest that the following would work  Dim _typeName As System.String = "System.Int32"  Dim _list As List(Of _typeName)

Comment: @Enigmativity: that would suggest that the following would work: -   Dim _typeName As System.String = "System.Int32" : Dim _list As List(Of _typeName),  but it doesn't, could you exemplify?

Comment: @SalimanderNel - No, that doesn't work. `_typeName` is a run-time variable. Generics only work at compile-time. This works at run-time - `Dim _typeName = "System.Int32" : Dim _type = Type.GetType(_typeName) : Dim _listType = GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(_type) : Dim instance = Activator.CreateInstance(_listType)` - but it probably doesn't help you greatly as `instance` is declared at compile-time as an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a List with a dynamic type, use [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_), although bear in mind this likely won't work if [strict mode is turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

```
Dim _list = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(List(Of)).MakeGenericType(_type))
```

Note, however, that lists created in this way don't have access to extension methods, like the LINQ methods.